# AutoRoute implementing a BottomNavigationBar (RouteData operation requested with a context…)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an error that I can't solve with the [AutoRoute package](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route). I think I've done everything I need to do but I still get this error no matter what I do. Do you have any ideas?

> RouteData operation requested with a context that does not include an
> RouteData.

In the simulator:

> RouteData operation requested with a context that does not include an
> RouteData. The context used to retrieve the RouteData must be that of
> a widget that is a descendant of a AutoRoutePage.

Code:

```dart
// AppRouter

import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';

...

part 'app_router.gr.dart';

@AutoRouterConfig()
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  @override
  RouteType get defaultRouteType => const RouteType.cupertino();

  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
    AutoRoute(page: HomeRoute.page, initial: true),
    AutoRoute(page: HourRoute.page),
    AutoRoute(page: TicketRoute.page),
    AutoRoute(page: ProfileRoute.page),
  ];
}

// Main and MyApp

import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:oktoast/oktoast.dart';

...

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await initializeDependencies();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final _appRouter = AppRouter();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => LocalStopCubit(
            locator<DatabaseRepository>(),
          )..getAllSavedStops(),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => RemoteStopCubit(
            locator<ApiRepository>(),
          )..getStops(),
        )
      ],
      child: OKToast(
        child: MaterialApp.router(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
          routerDelegate: AutoRouterDelegate(
            _appRouter,
            navigatorObservers: () => [
              AppRouteObserver(),
            ],
          ),
          title: appTitle,
          theme: AppTheme.light,
          builder: (context, child) => AutoTabsRouter(
            routes: const [
              HomeRoute(),
              HourRoute(),
            ],
            transitionBuilder: (context,child,animation)=> FadeTransition(
              opacity: animation,
              child: child,
            ),
            // router: _appRouter,
            builder: (context, child) {
              final tabsRouter = AutoTabsRouter.of(context);

              return Scaffold(
                body: child,
                bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                  currentIndex: tabsRouter.activeIndex,
                  onTap: tabsRouter.setActiveIndex,
                  items: const [
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                      label: 'Home',
                    ),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
                      label: 'Hour',
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```